# Run Multi lifecycleScope on Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-lifecycle, kotlin-flow

I have a Home Fragment, and inside that`onCreateView` fragment, I have 2 function, that will execute `lifecycleScope`.

The first `lifecycleScope` will used to get all the list of `cashFlow`, and the second `lifecycleScope` will use to get all the total of `outcome` and `income`.

Here is the `onCreateView`

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false) as ConstraintLayout
    btnNewOutcome(content)
    btnNewIncome(content)

    val cashFlowDao = (activity?.applicationContext as CashFlowApp).db.cashFlowDao()
    loadCashFlow(cashFlowDao, content)
    loadTotalTransaction(cashFlowDao, content)
    return content
}
```

This is the first `lifecycleScope` that will used to get all the `cashFlow` history,

```
private fun loadCashFlow(cashFlowDao: CashFlowDao, content: View) {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        cashFlowDao.fetchAllCashFlow().collect {
            val cashFlowList = ArrayList(it)
            setupHistoryCashFlow(cashFlowList, cashFlowDao, content)
        }
    }
}
```

This is the second `lifecycleScope` that will used to get the total of `cashFlow`,

```
private fun loadTotalTransaction(cashFlowDao: CashFlowDao, content: View) {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        val totalIncome: Int = cashFlowDao.calculateIncome(Constant.INCOME)
        val totalOutcome: Int = cashFlowDao.calculateIncome(Constant.OUTCOME)
        Log.e("Total", totalIncome.toString())
        setupTotalTransaction(totalIncome, totalOutcome, content)
    }
}
```

When trying to run the application, it will crash with this error message.
[image]

You can find the repository on this link, and pay attention on `HomeFragment` and `MainActivity`
https://github.com/gandarain/money_track_app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the function `calculateIncome()` is not `suspend`, and it is blocking the current thread (Main Thread).
Marking `calculateIncome()` function as `suspend` in `CashFlowDao` should solve the problem. It will not block the Main Thread.

In `CashFlowDao` class:

```
suspend fun calculateIncome(...): Int
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I was wonder.
I have other function on CashFlowDao, fetchAllCashFlow, i did not put suspend on that function, but it still working fine.
For this calculateOutcome i did not put suspend, and it retun error.

Do you know why?

Comment: Dao functions that return `Flow` are calculated lazily without blocking the current thread, they start execution when consumer consumes it by calling one of the terminal operators, like `collect` in your case.